# Get data from relationship using Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get data from Menu and SubMenu table using Eloquent model instead of join.

My Menucontroller

```
class MenuController extends Controller
{
// Where ever you want your menu
    public function menu()
    {

        $menu = Menu::all()->load('submenu');

    return view('menu',compact('menu'));
    }
}
```

My menu Model is

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Menu extends Model
{


    public function submenu()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SubMenu::class);
    }
}
```

My submenu model is

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class SubMenu extends Model
{
    public function menu()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Menu::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `with` function to eager load the `Submenu` from the `Menu`, you can check the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
class MenuController extends Controller
{
    public function menu()
    {

        $menu = Menu::with('submenu')->all();
        return view('menu',compact('menu'));
    }
}
```

In your blade view you have access to the object:

```
@foreach ($menu as $menu_obj)
    <p>This is the menu: {{ $menu_obj }}</p>
    <p>This is the submenu: {{ $menu_obj->submenu }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: same error   
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Menu' not found
in MenuController.php (line 18)
at MenuController->menu()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(MenuController), 'menu'), array())
in Controller.php (line 55)

Comment: if i use return SubMenu::get() in controller function it return me db data without error

Comment: Before your class declaration you have to import the Menu class
`use App\Menu;` check where the Menu.php class is and adjust the namespace if you need to.